# Help with classes and member variables in C++

Tags: c++

Ok I have two classes: Image and Scene. Now in the Image header file, I defined three private variables: xcoord, ycoord, and index (as well as their respective public getter methods).

I have another class named Scene. Scene is not a subclass of Image. Scene has two member variables: `int maximum` and `Image **images`. Now in Scene, I have some methods that attempt to access the member variables of the Image class. For example:

```
int beginX =this->images[i].getXcoord;
int beginY =this->images[i].getYcoord;
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
 error: request for member ‘getXcoord’ in ‘*(((Image**)((const Scene*)this)->Scene::images) + ((Image**)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’, which is of non-class type ‘Image*’

scene.cpp:135: error: request for member ‘getYcoord’ in ‘*(((Image**)((const Scene*)this)->Scene::images) + ((Image**)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’, which is of non-class type ‘Image*’
```

In my scene.cpp file, I have included scene.h which includes image.h, so I'm pretty sure everything is properly linked. Is it apparent what my problem is or will I have to provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call methods so try:

```
int beginX = this->images[i]->getXcoord();
int beginY = this->images[i]->getYcoord();
```

otherwise the compiler is looking for a member variable and not a getter method

Comment: Ya youre right. Lemme fix that and check again, but I'm pretty sure Ill have more errors.

Answer (score 0):

If `this->images` is an `Image**`, then `this->images[i]` is an `Image*`.

Replace the dots with arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the images array holds pointers to classes

try 
`int beginX =this->images[i]->getXcoord;`

also if getXcoord is a function you need to call it like this

`int beginX =this->images[i]->getXcoord();`

lastly you dont need `this->` its implied so use

`int beginX = images[i]->getXcoord();`

DC

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. It should be:

```
 int beginX = this->images[i]->getXcoord();
```

The error message isn't allowing the '.' operator on the Image* which is not a class-type object.